# SSIS How to create an expression that runs a task if a specific predecessor task has run

Tags: ssis

I currently have an ETL package that downloads files and then loads them into a database.

When I have downloaded the files and processed them, I place the files into an archive folder. However, as I truncate the staging table each time I run the process if any new files are downloaded, I need to reload the archive files in a separate process.

I have 2 foreach containers, 1 loads the new files whilst the new container loads the archived files.

What I want to do is create an expression on the archive foreach loop that will only run if the SQL task that truncates the table is completed.

Do I create a variable of type boolean that changes the value to 1 if the task is run and use that in my expression? If so how could I achieve this?

Comment: Would it be equally valid if all the files were in the same folder and the truncate and reload only occurred if a new file was downloaded?

Comment: I am unsure why you are reloaded all archived files? Why not process the new file into the existing table?